# Understanding Docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am finding it a little hard to grasp the Dockerfile. Consider the following commands in the dockerfile which creates a tomcat image:

```
 RUN wget -q https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-${TOMCAT_MAJOR_VERSION}/v${TOMCAT_MINOR_VERSION}/bin/apache-tomcat-${TOMCAT_MINOR_VERSION}.tar.gz &&\
tar zxf apache-tomcat-*.tar.gz

 ADD helloWorld.war ${CATALINA_HOME}/webapps/

 CMD ["/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat.sh"]
```

I am downloading the tomcat and adding a war file and then starting the tomcat.

1. Now what I am not understanding is that when do the RUN, ADD and CMD execute? Do they execute when I do docker build or docker run?
2. If they execute during docker run, where will they get my helloWorld.war from? Is the docker image a package with helloWorld.war and a set of commands from dockerfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `RUN` and `ADD` will be running at build time (`docker build`) and `CMD/ENTRYPOINT` will be executed at run time(`docker run`).

   - `RUN` will be executed while building the image and corresponding layer is added to the docker image.
   - `CMD` is the default command executed whenever the container started.
   - `ADD/COPY` copies the files from host to docker image while building the image.
2. helloWorld.war will be packed inside the docker image. If you want to provide the war file at `docker run`, you can use [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/). You can mount webapps directory of your tomcat.

`docker run -v /path/to/war/file/in/host:/path/to/webapps/war/in/container tomcat`

Answer (score 0):

RUN and ADD commands execute when you build your image.
CMD is the default command executed when you run your image.
CMD runs inside the container, so it gets helloWorld.war from "inside" (the first layer) the container.